# In PHP string I want extract ID and replace with name player

Tags: php, string, function, replace, extract

I would like to extract the #ID1234 and use function to replace it with name in link form.

The ID number is dynamic.

So from

```
$string = 'Hello I am #ID1234 and rest of the text';
```

To

```
$string = 'Hello I and <a href="#">John</a> and rest of the text';
```

I need function to get name and sort link. I am okay most code to not sure how get extact #ID1234 convert into just player number 1234.

The player number can be put anyway easy and fast to extract ideas welcome ie {1234}

Comment: Is it always going to be in the same format, e.g. `#` followed by `ID` followed by only numbers?

Comment: just use `str_replace`.

Comment: `$string = str_replace('#ID1234', '<a href="#">John</a>', $string);`

Comment: It will always be whatever we decide here. New database so doesn't matter.

Comment: But ID number changes would need look up each time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a function `get_name($id)` returns the name of the user, try:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $string, $id);
$name = get_name($id)
preg_replace("/#ID[0-9]*/", "<a href='/whatever_url?id=".$id."'>".$name."</a>", $string);
```

Comment: Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /

Comment: Well, did it work? If so, please accept the answer, or let us know so we can help.